# What way can I pass data to separate views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am not sure the title is correct for the issue, but I did not know how else to construct it.

I've got `profile.blade.php` and `scripts.blade.php` files - one is the view itself, and the other one contains just custom JS. In the first one I have this line:

```
<div id="age" class="inline-block pull-left"></div>
```

And the scripts has:

```
<script>
    function getAge(dateString) {
    ...
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var age = getAge(new Date({{ $user->birthdate }}));
        $("#age").text("(" + age + " years old)");
    });
</script>
```

And then I have a `master_layout` view:

```
...
    @include('scripts')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
...
</body>
```

Finally, the controller:

```
public function getPersonalProfile()
{
   $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
   return View::make('account.profile')->with('user', $user);
}
```

So, I get error upon trying to use the `{{ $user->birthdate }}` part, that the `$user` variable does not exist. If I write is as

```
var age = getAge(new Date("1987-03-23"));
```

then it's all fine calculated and shown. But, of course, I want it with the data passed from the controller. :D

In my understanding, everything (the master layout, containing the view and the scripts part) is loaded into one whole HTML, but apparently my understanding is wrong...

Of course, I could calculate this in the controller and pass it to the view, but I would like to know if there is a way to communicate like that, between the views.

I need to pass the `$user` data to the `profile` view, because I use it for other things, than the age, as well.
How can I make use of the data from the model, in the `scripts` ?

Comment: Try passing the `$user` variable as a parameter to the included view: `@include('scripts', ['user' => $user])`.

Comment: I've just tried setting up a test with your structure and it worked for me (event without explicitly passing the `$user` variable as I've suggested in my previous comment).

Comment: Just to make sure, in your `profile.blade.php` view do you have the correct `@extends` and `@section` statements to extend the layour view? Or do you just have the _one_ line `<div id="age" class="inline-block pull-left"></div>` as you said in your question?

Comment: Yes, but then I have to create the `scripts` view from the Controller... The `profile` view is too big and there is no point posting here everything, because the only relevant line is the `div` that I showed.

Comment: @Bogdan, I do have the correct usage of `@extends` and `@section` :)

Comment: Here's what I've tried tried as a test reduced to the bare minimum, to see if the `$user` variable is passed to the `scrips` view: http://laravel.io/bin/wJYW9. Try it and see if to works for you. If it does it means the problems is specific to your code.

Comment: Also, as a side note, you don't need to search for the authenticated user in the database with `User::find(Auth::user()->id);`, the authentication system already holds that model in `Auth::user()`. So `$user = Auth::user();` is the same thing, without the extra query to the database.